# window.plugins object is undefined in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I'm making an app in cordova. I've installed some plugins, but problem is that I cannot use those plugins as when I try to call them like `window.plugins.googleplus.login` then it says `property 'plugins' does not exists on window`. So I searched from solution and they said use `window['plugins']` I tried that too, but now it says `undefined`.

I tried `cordova plugins ls` and it lists all my plugins. Also checked available plugins in `android.json`, all plugins are there. Can anyone help me why it is `undefined`? My `index.html` looks like below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Scrmbl</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <base href="./">
  <script type=”text/javascript” src="cordova.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <app-root>
    <center>
      <div style="margin-top: 200px;">

        <img src="./assets_v2/images/icon.png" alt="" >
        <br><br>
        <img src="./assets_v2/images/preloader.gif" alt="">
      </div>
    </center>
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
cordova --version
8.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are calling it without `deviceready`. None of the **googleplus** methods should be called before `deviceready` has fired. The plugin should be called when everything's ready for the plugin to be called.

Example:

`document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false); function deviceReady() { 
console.log('Device is ready!'); window.plugins.googleplus.trySilentLogin(...); }`

Reference [visit here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)

Comment: The issue is not when it is called. The syntax window["plugins"] works, but cordova compiles it back to the dot notation, which breaks the code after the build.